# Dynamic child component via router in angular2

Tags: angular

I have master detail kind of app configured via routes.

```
    Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/master',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'master',
        component: MasterComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: DetailsComponent
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
```

html for master component

```
<div>...</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

It works perfectly fine. But now my child has different types and data. so Instead of DetailsComponent I want to render DetailsType1Component, DetailsType2Component, DetailsType3Component... which are fixed and predefined. I want to fetch data based on id present in route, then decide what type of child it is, then render one of DetailsType1Component...

How can that be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular wants the routes to be static. It provides the [Router.resetConfig](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig) function if you need some dynamic, but I'd better use another approach here. You can load your details components dynamically depending on the provided id. Let's say we have some Details Component container element:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'details-container',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  `
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  content

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    switch (id) {
      case '1':
        this.content = DetailsType1Component
        break
      case '2':
        this.content = DetailsType2Component
        break
      default:
        this.content = DetailsTypeDefaultComponent
    }
  }
}
```

It uses the `*ngComponentOutlet` directive to load a component you need. Which one exactly is decided inside the constructor after reading the `id` parameter from the url.

[**Plunkr**](https://embed.plnkr.co/ucLkNLe8paJkgE9bXgrw/)

Comment: No, the ngComponentOutlet directive appeared in Angular 4.3. If your version on lower you should use ComponentFactoryResolver as @JayDeeEss showed.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a common detail container component and route your router to that and in that component, you can load your component dynamically depending on your condition. check [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)!

container.component.ts

```
export class ContainerComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() component: Type<any>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.component) this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
   let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);

    let viewContainerRef = this.messageHost.viewContainerRef;

    viewContainerRef.clear();

    viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

container.component.html

```
<div>
        <!-- placeholder for dynamic components -->
        <ng-template message-host></ng-template>
</div>
```

In the above example, its loading dynamic component, passed by @Input() property

Comment: Thanks. this works with lower version of angular as well.